# Am I a douche for quitting my job?

Tags: resignation, job-change, education

So, let's start.
For the last 2 years I've been working as web developer in this X company.
Let me go back to how I got my job and my relations to certain people there.
It was back in early 2018 when a friend of mine showed me an ad for internship for aforementioned X company. Now, I know that one of my relatives is actually a managing director for that company, so I contact him and ask about this internship, at the time I didn't have a lot of working experience so I liked the fact that no experience was asked for since after all it is an internship, but there would still be a round of interviews and some test tasks to do. Since my cousin is managing director and he usually conducts these interviews, he actually appointed 2 team leads to be in charge of my interview (they had no idea we were related until after I got the job). So this interview went the best possible way and I was contacted the next day to see if I'm able to start working right next week.

So in the mean time I have been an employee at this X company and everything was nice and good, but then I decided to apply to a university in a city that is around ~270 kilometers away from where I live and work. This is DL (distance learning) type of university, where I watch live lessons online and only go to university to take my exams and do other formal stuff when needed.

I have been to this city 5 times already and it's really tiring, I take a bus at 05:00 and I arrive there at around 11:30, do what I need and I wait for my return ride which is at 16:00 and I'm home at around 10:30. This is very tiring for me, and since exams and other things take place mostly during week days I need to take a day or two off from work to attend to these.

So today, I asked my cousin/director to have a talk in private and I told him that I would like to quit due to these reasons, I also said that I won't quit on my own, but I said that when "good" opportunity arrives he should let me know so I can do what I need and leave, he didn't seem too happy about this and neither was I, but it's really hard to travel for such a long time, especially when I'm using my free days from work to do it, also I wold be really tired the next day at work.

All of this lead to noticeable lack of focus at work and often I just get lost in my thoughts while in the middle of something.
One of the questions I got at the interview was: "Do you plan to go anywhere in the near future, because we need someone who will stay?", and I said yes, but college happened and... yeah.

Am I being a douche here, I definitely feel like one, even more so because it's my cousin who's in charge of employees, how much should I stay at a company in order  not to be considered to have left in "near future"?

I'm very much willing to stay until the end of year, but I wanted to prepare him beforehand so he can plan accordingly.

> TLDR: Worked at a company for the last 2 years, managing director is
>   also my relative. I said I won't be leaving in the near future and
>   today I told him to plan on me quitting when favorable opportunity
>   arises.

Comment: Closed for being opinion-based? Most questions in this site are opinion-based... workplace etiquette is not exactly exact science...

Comment: @obe My guess is that the close voters saw the question as currently worded as being too much about the familial relationship (was I a jerk to my cousin) and not the workplace (was this unprofessional). I considered re-wording it but both "Is this enough notice" and "is this too short a tenure" are almost certainly both duplicates.

Comment: @bsmp thanks! However, if I'm not mistaken a question can also be marked as off-topic or duplicate, but the closers chose "opinion-based", so that's what I responded to. As to the focus on familial relationship - while it can always be argued that a text can be rephrased "better", having relatives in the workplace is a thing, and IMO it's ok to have in [The Workplace], even if it partly touches on the family side. The bottom-line question seems valid ("how much should I stay at a company in order not to be considered to have left in "near future"").

Comment: I know from personal experience how daunting it is to spend 20, 30, 60 minutes on a question, just to have it closed 30 seconds after posting, because of some vague criteria, or, more likely, trigger-happy close-voters. That is not to say that every question needs to be accepted, but, as someone who has close vote permissions on another site in the network, I try to err on the side of caution, and only vote to close in very clear cases, usually in questions where it's obvious that the asker didn't put in even a minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people feel this sort of guilt when quitting a job. I did at my previous one and I didn't even have the family ties as a reason to stay.

I'm currently going through a very similar situation, I'm in a job I got through a friend of the family. Quitting would be really tough, but sometimes it's necessary.

To cut a long answer short: **no you're not a douche**.

Circumstances change and any reasonable person will accept that. The fact you've given so much notice and have been flexible about an end date is extremely generous (perhaps inadvisable).

Don't sweat it.

---

P.S. 2 years in one company for a web developer is kind of the norm in a lot of places.

Comment: Thanks man, I just don't want to disappoint my cousin, that's all, everyone was really  fair to me as much as possible, don't want any negative memories.

Comment: I get that, it can be tough when you feel like you're letting people down but at the end of the day, it's a professional decision and is the best decision for you

Answer (score 2):

**Your cousin/director is absurdly spoiled**

> I'm very much willing to stay until the end of year, but I wanted to prepare him beforehand so he can plan accordingly.

Virtually no external employee would give this much notice. Your cousin would get two weeks notice and they would be gone. For someone who is not family, "near future" might be 2 months if the employee were exceedingly generous.

You are not a douche. You are bending over backward to accommodate them.

Comment: Nah, he is not spoiled, he didn't try to force me to stay or say anything bad about it, but it's just that he didn't seem completely fine with (no one would be) and that's what's making me give second thoughts to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling to understand your situation. You've been working at this company for 2 years, started college, and it's too much now? Then no, you need to prioritize your education.
If you only have to go to school once a week, or so, then consider negotiating a different set of times so that you aren't exhausted for that. You'll present yourself as a better employee by knowing the limits AND you can show that they'll get better value by accommodating your schedule.

Comment: I'm 26, I applied at college in order to get my diploma so I can go work abroad as it's usually a first thing they ask for in a job ad. Change of work schedule is not an option, few people already tried it and we can't work remotely either. It's just that I have 20 vacation days per year, and I would have to use most if not all of these for college related stuff.

Comment: That's always the trade off. Your career with a degree will open more doors for that type of work, and potentially far more money, than what you're making now. At my job we (not my choice) will not even look at people without a 4 year degree.

20 days is a lot, but a professional lot may be worth even more. Theoretically my employment is 'unlimited' vacation days, of which I used quite a bit after a stroke left me unable to work for 2 months.

Do the degree. IMHO. Unless it's not an employable field...